# Changed from Navigation to TabBar, CoreData does not load

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I changed my Navigation Controller to Tab Bar Controller, then I wanted to compile the app. But it does not load my managedContext anymore.

This is my launching code when I load the app:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
        let viewController = navController.topViewController as? ViewController else {
            return true
    }
    viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Therefore I tried to edit the code like this:

Edit:

```
       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        //let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller



        guard let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
            let navController = tabController.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController,
            let viewController = navController.topViewController as? ViewController else {
                return true

        }
//  Version that works for UINavigationCOntroller 
//        guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
//            let viewController = navController.topViewController as? ViewController else {
//                return true
//        }
        viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

I changed the code, but I still can not load managedContext, and it returns nil when I want to use it in ViewController, I also set the initial Viewcontroller to the tabBarController.

Comment: Where are you setting `rootviewcontroller` for your `window`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I marked "Is initial View Controller" on the Storyboard.

Comment: Is that storyboard is main?

Comment: yes , i only have one storyboard

Comment: Your rootviewcontroller is still not Tabbarcontroller

Comment: how can I set it as rootviewcontroller than? and how can i load the managedContext so I can use it in the ViewController?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163433/discussion-between-umair-aamir-and-pafi).

Answer (score 0):

Set rootviewcontroller for your window first and then right your logic afterwards.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(<StoryboardName>, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.initializeInitialViewController()
    window.rootViewController = controller
        guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
            let viewController = navController.moreNavigationController as? ViewController else {
                return true
        }
        viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return
```

Comment: Again thanks for helping. I edited the question and tried your solution, but it still does not work.